# Check If UItextView Text Is Empty Once

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextview

I want to call an animation when my UITextView is empty and again when it is not empty.

I get the UITextView changes in the delegate method below;

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {

}
```

However, this checks if the UITextView is empty every time it changes. I only want to call this once.

Is there any method for this?

Comment: Hi, I think you can use a flag to detect the first time is empty or not

Answer (score 0):

This delegate is handled by `UIKit`, therefore is not possible to select **when** it is called. However, there are these other options according to [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextviewdelegate):

```swift
func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView)
func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView)
```